# Why do you need $request->ips() in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Laravel offers a function called `$request->ip()` (instance of `Illuminate/Http/Request`). This function is very useful. In the API documentation (https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_ips) I have now seen that there is also the function `ips()`. This is supposed to return the IP addresses to the clients. This surprises me. I thought there was always only one client IP. How can it be that this function exists? And I'm sure I'm missing something and Laravel has a reason to offer this function. I don't know what it is. I have also tried the function and get an array with only one IP.

Answer (score 1):

In a request, there may be more than one `IP` address such as in instances where a proxy is involved. The `$request->ip()` function attempts to return the `ip address` the request originated from using the `X-FORWARDED-FOR` header. The `$request->ips()` function attempts to return all `IP` addresses for a request which would include proxies if they have been involve d.

Have a look at the [Symfony `HttpFoundation Request` source code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.1/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L758) for more information.

Comment: if i would compare the result list of ips() with ip() which one would be match? the first IP or the last one? Do you happen to know that? But thanks for good answer. merci

Comment: @MaikLowrey The last `ip` element in the `ips()` array should be the "real" client and be the same as `ip()`.

Comment: Many thanks for your time! That is what i needed to understand.

Answer (score 0):

This method adds original and proxy chain IP's from `X-Forwarded-For` header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For

Comment: merci for the answer! if i would compare the result list of ips() with ip() which one would be match? the first IP or the last one? Do you happen to know that?